# Powershell regex -replace matches more often than it should

Tags: powershell

I have the following Regular Expression: `([a-z])([A-Z])`

When I plug it into RegEx 101 it seems to work perfectly: https://regex101.com/r/vhifNL/1

[image: RegEx Example]

But when I plug it into Powershell to have the matches replaced with dashes, it goes crazy:

```
"JavaScript" -replace '([a-z])([A-Z])', '$1-$2'
```

I expect to get `Java-Script`.  But instead I get:

> J-av-aS-cr-ip-t

**Why is it not matching the same way that RegEx101 has it match?**

<sup><sub>**NOTE:** This question is not tagged with RegEx on purpose.  I would take it as a kindness if no-one added it.  The RegEx folks have a different set of rules they run by for questions and will likely close my question.</sub></sup>

Comment: Wow, not a regex expert but yeah this seems wrong. `([regex]"[\W_]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])").Replace("S2MA Test Application","-")` works fine tho.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - That is AMAZING!  Thank so much for this.  Like most who use RegEx, I care more about getting a working solution and this did it!   Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, no problem, still, your finding is very weird to me lol. So, if you use `([regex]"[\W_]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])").Matches("S2MA Test Application")` you'll see the same matches as in `regex101` I'm honestly not sure if this is intended or a bug!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PowerShell's [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), like all PowerShell operators that can operate on strings** (notably `-match`, `-eq`, `-like`, `-contains` and their negated counterparts), and **like PowerShell in general, is case-*insensitive* by default**.

However, all such operators have **case-*sensitive* variants,** selected by simply **prepending `c` to the operator name**, namely **`-creplace`** in the case at hand:

```
PS> "JavaScript" -creplace '([a-z])([A-Z])', '$1-$2'
Java-Script
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

Due to `-replace` being case-*insensitive* (which you can optionally signal explicitly with the
`-ireplace` alias), your regex was essentially equivalent to:

```
([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])
```

and therefore matched *any two consecutive (ASCII-range) letters*, and not the desired transition from a lowercase to an uppercase letter.

Comment: That is just crazy!  I had no idea!  I can't believe this is not easier see on internet examples.  Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Oh wow, I feel so stupid now lol As always the right answer!

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon :) It's easy to get confused with a regex that seemingly explicitly makes case distinctions; it pays to keep in mind that everything in PowerShell is case-INsensitive by default, unless requested otherwise.